# How to ignore case sensitivity in Oracle database query

Tags: sql, oracle, case-sensitive

I have string with upper and lower case characters, How can I ignore case sensitivity.

I have tried with COLLET,UPPERCASE,LOWERCASE
It is not working.
is there any other way to ignore?

Comment: Can you show what you tried in statement?

Comment: The keyword is UPPER

Comment: Something like `WHERE UPPER(myColumn) = UPPER(myValue)`. Of course, using `LOWER` is OK as well.

Comment: @RobertKock why don't your comment as an answer. This way the question will be formally answered

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst: check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upper, and lower method are ok, but if you are looking for something more sophisticated  try this.

```
create table table_test (a varchar2(100));

insert into table_test values( 'ABC');
insert into table_test values( 'abc');
insert into table_test values( 'AbC');

alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC; 
-- how to compare string 
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI;  --//or alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;  
-- how to sort string  
-- the magic starts here 
    select * from table_test where a = 'ABC'
```

And full description of different method of sorting and comparing:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm#CIHJBFAD

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
WHERE UPPER(myColumn) = UPPER(myValue)
```

or, of course:

```
WHERE LOWER(myColumn) = LOWER(myValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

use either upper or lower on both sides just like Robert Kock has mentioned.
if the joins are not matching after using upper/lower it could be due to trailing spaces in your data. 
In that case you can also use trim to remove unwanted trailing spaces

```
upper(trim(column1)) = upper(trim(column2))
```

or

```
lower(trim(column1)) = lower(trim(column2))
```